# Dependency injection with JavaFX gives NullPointerExceptions

Tags: spring, spring-boot, javafx, dependency-injection, spring-data-jpa

I want to mix Java FX and Spring Data. I found video about this problem https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u0dEf-QN-90&t=3s and I implemented it in my code. In consequence my UI working but I couldn't inject dependency to TaskRepository. I had been trying in difrent ways to inject anything and always I get same error, that my dependency is null. What am I doing wrong?

addingWindow.fxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Slider?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextArea?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>

<HBox maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/16" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="pl.projektyjava.listToDoJavaFX.fxmlcontrollers.AddingWindowController">
   <children>
      <VBox prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="473.0" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS">
         <children>
            <Label alignment="TOP_CENTER" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" text="Tytuł" textAlignment="CENTER" />
            <TextField fx:id="title" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS" />
            <Label alignment="TOP_CENTER" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" text="Opis" textAlignment="CENTER" />
            <TextArea fx:id="description" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS" />
            <HBox maxHeight="-Infinity" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS">
               <children>
                  <Button fx:id="listOfQuest" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Lista Zadań" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS" />
                  <Button fx:id="addQuest" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Dodaj zadanie" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS" />
               </children>
            </HBox>
         </children>
      </VBox>
      <Slider fx:id="priority" blockIncrement="1.0" majorTickUnit="1.0" max="5.0" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" minorTickCount="0" orientation="VERTICAL" showTickLabels="true" showTickMarks="true" snapToTicks="true" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS" />
   </children>
</HBox>
```

pl.projektyjava.listToDoJavaFX.appinitialization. Initialization

```
package pl.projektyjava.listToDoJavaFX.appinitialization;

import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationListener;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.io.IOException;

@Component
public class Initialization implements ApplicationListener<StarterClass.StageReadyEvent>{




    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(StarterClass.StageReadyEvent event) {
        Stage stage = event.getStage();
        HBox mainPane= null;
        try {
            mainPane = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/addingWindow.fxml"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Scene scene=new Scene(mainPane);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

pl.projektyjava.listToDoJavaFX.appinitialization.ListToDoJavaFXApplication

```
package pl.projektyjava.listToDoJavaFX.appinitialization;


import javafx.application.Application;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class ListToDoJavaFxApplication  {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(StarterClass.class, args);

    }
}
```

pl.projektyjava.listToDoJavaFX.appinitialization.StarterClass

```
package pl.projektyjava.listToDoJavaFX.appinitialization;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationEvent;
import org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class StarterClass extends Application {

    private ConfigurableApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Override
    public void init()  {


        applicationContext=new SpringApplicationBuilder(ListToDoJavaFxApplication.class).run();
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage)  {

        applicationContext.publishEvent(new StageReadyEvent(stage));

    }

    @Override
    public void stop()  {
        applicationContext.close();
        Platform.exit();
    }

    static class StageReadyEvent extends ApplicationEvent {
        public StageReadyEvent (Stage stage){
            super(stage);
        }
        public Stage getStage(){
           return ((Stage) getSource());
        }
    }
}
```

pl.projektyjava.listToDoJavaFX.body.Task

```
package pl.projektyjava.listToDoJavaFX.body;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class Task {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String title;
    private String description;
    private double priority;

    public Task(String title, String description, double priority) {
        this.title = title;
        this.description = description;
        this.priority = priority;
    }

    public Task() {
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public double getPriority() {
        return priority;
    }

    public void setPriority(double priority) {
        this.priority = priority;
    }
}
```

pl.projektyjava.listToDoJavaFX.body.TaskRepository

```
package pl.projektyjava.listToDoJavaFX.body;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface TaskRepository extends CrudRepository<Task, Long> {
}
```

pl.projektyjava.listToDoJavaFX.fxmlcontrollers.AddingWindowController

```
package pl.projektyjava.listToDoJavaFX.fxmlcontrollers;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Slider;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import pl.projektyjava.listToDoJavaFX.body.Task;
import pl.projektyjava.listToDoJavaFX.body.TaskRepository;

@Controller
public class AddingWindowController {

    @Autowired
    TaskRepository taskRepository;

    @FXML
    private TextField title;

    @FXML
    private TextArea description;

    @FXML
    private Button listOfQuest;

    @FXML
    private Button addQuest;

    @FXML
    private Slider priority;

    public void initialize() {
        addQuest.setOnAction(event -> {
            String titleText = title.getText();
            String descriptionText = description.getText();
            double priorityVal = priority.getValue();

            Task task = new Task(titleText, descriptionText, priorityVal);
            taskRepository.save(task);

        });
    }

}
```

and ERROR:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "pl.projektyjava.listToDoJavaFX.body.TaskRepository.save(Object)" because "this.taskRepository" is null
    at pl.projektyjava.listToDoJavaFX.fxmlcontrollers.AddingWindowController.lambda$initialize$0(AddingWindowController.java:41)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:234)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8792)
    at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:203)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:208)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.inputmap.InputMap.handle(InputMap.java:274)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:247)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:234)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3861)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1854)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2587)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:409)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:299)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$2(GlassViewEventHandler.java:447)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:413)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:446)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:556)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:942)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:174)
```

After adding `ControlerFactory` to `FXMLLoader` I have this:

```
javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
/B:/Projekty/1%20PROJEKT/listToDo-JavaFX/listToDo-JavaFX/target/classes/addingWindow.fxml:11

    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2707)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2685)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2548)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2517)
    at pl.projektyjava.listToDoJavaFX.appinitialization.Initialization.onApplicationEvent(Initialization.java:28)
    at pl.projektyjava.listToDoJavaFX.appinitialization.Initialization.onApplicationEvent(Initialization.java:14)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:176)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:169)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:143)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:421)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:378)
    at pl.projektyjava.listToDoJavaFX.appinitialization.StarterClass.start(StarterClass.java:26)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:849)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:474)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:447)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:446)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:174)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:831)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'pl.projektyjava.listToDoJavaFX.fxmlcontrollers.AddingWindowController' available
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:351)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:342)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1172)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:940)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$InstanceDeclarationElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:982)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:229)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:754)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:2808)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2634)
    ... 19 more
Exception in Application start method
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
2021-04-23 19:47:00.791  INFO 12928 --- [lication Thread] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2021-04-23 19:47:00.794  INFO 12928 --- [lication Thread] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2021-04-23 19:47:00.800  INFO 12928 --- [lication Thread] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:903)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:198)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:831)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Root cannot be null
    at javafx.scene.Scene.<init>(Scene.java:345)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.<init>(Scene.java:207)
    at pl.projektyjava.listToDoJavaFX.appinitialization.Initialization.onApplicationEvent(Initialization.java:32)
    at pl.projektyjava.listToDoJavaFX.appinitialization.Initialization.onApplicationEvent(Initialization.java:14)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:176)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:169)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:143)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:421)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:378)
    at pl.projektyjava.listToDoJavaFX.appinitialization.StarterClass.start(StarterClass.java:26)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:849)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:474)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:447)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:446)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:174)
    ... 1 more

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: More that anything, I'd be concerned that the error for initializing the repository is showing up on the FXAT.  That's potentially a really big problem.  There needs to be a way to have the SpringBoot initialization stuff start from main() before (or after) it calls the Application.launch() method, but not from inside Application.launch(), as it seems to be here.

Comment: @DaveB There isn't an error initializing the repository, though. The reference to the repository simply isn't injected into the controller (because the controller isn't managed by spring). The Spring initialization is being done in `init()`, which is called on the main thread prior to `start()` being invoked on the FX application thread, as is appropriate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, the `FXMLLoader` will create controller instances by calling the no-argument constructor. Consequently, the `AddingWindowController` instance that's created is not managed by Spring, and Spring cannot inject `@Autowired` dependencies into it. (Basically, the Spring `ApplicationContext` has no knowledge that the `AddingWindowController` instance exists.)

You can supply a `ControllerFactory` to the `FXMLLoader` which asks that the controller is created by the spring application context:

```
@Component
public class Initialization implements ApplicationListener<StarterClass.StageReadyEvent>{


    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext ;

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(StarterClass.StageReadyEvent event) {
        Stage stage = event.getStage();
        HBox mainPane= null;
        try {
            FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/addingWindow.fxml"));
            fxmlLoader.setControllerFactory(applicationContext::getBean);
            mainPane = fxmlLoader.load();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Scene scene=new Scene(mainPane);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

Also note that you should create a new controller instance each time the FXML is loaded, so JavaFX controllers should have prototype scope. It probably doesn't matter too much, but the `@Controller` annotation in Spring is really intended for MVC controllers in a web application, so the `@Component` stereotype is really more appropriate here:

```
@Component
@Scope("prototype")
public class AddingWindowController {

    // ...

}
```

Comment: I did it and I get other error (it is in the edited question).

Comment: @ZygmuntSześcian Then you additionally have errors associated with Spring locating the repository class, as described in JAsgorov's answer

Answer (score 0):

By default @SpringBootApplication does componentscan in its own folder and underneath. So just place ur ListToDoJavaFxApplication one folder up into pl.projektyjava.listToDoJavaFX

Alternatively just add `@ComponentScan(“pl.projektyjava.listToDoJavaFX”)` right above @SpringBootApplication defining component scan explicitly.

In general whenever auto wiring fails silently without BeanCreationException at startup it is a sign that ur component is not being found by component scan

Comment: In first way pop up the same error, but in second way (with ComponentScan) I have description like below

Comment: If this were the issue, then you'd get a different stack trace (essentially one saying Spring can't create the bean). You wouldn't simply have a null value for the injected field.